# dict remove also deletes key

Tags: dictionary, tcl

Tcl’s `dict remove` does not behave exactly as I expected. (I'm sure it's because my expectations are incorrect)

```
% set d [dict create]
% dict set d O1 C1 child1
O1 {C1 child1}
% dict set d O1 C2 child2
O1 {C1 child1 C2 child2}
% dict set d O2 C3 child3
O1 {C1 child1 C2 child2} O2 {C3 child3}
% dict remove $d O1 C1
O2 {C3 child3}
```

I was expecting the result to be:

```
O1 {C2 child2} O2 {C3 child3}
```

What's the reason for O1 C2 also being removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`dict unset`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm#M24) instead of [`dict remove`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm#M20).

`dict unset` will remove a key (and nested keys) with the value(s) associated to the deepest key.

```
% dict unset d O1 C1
O1 {C2 child2} O2 {C3 child3}
```

`dict remove` will remove all the keys at the first level of the dictionary and all the values under those keys:

```
% puts $d
O1 {C1 child1 C2 child2} O2 {C3 child3}
% dict set d O3 C4 child4
O1 {C1 child1 C2 child2} O2 {C3 child3} O3 {C4 child4}
% dict remove $d O1 O2
O3 {C4 child4}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you help me understand the documentation for `dict remove` which says 'Return a new dictionary that is a copy of an old one passed in as first argument except without mappings _for each of the keys listed_'.  To me `O1 C1` is a different key from `O1`, and so I expected the results to be different. Is it just me misunderstanding the meaning of `keys` or is the documentation slightly misleading? I'm guessing that a Tcl dictionary only really has one level of keys and nested keys only work for a select set of commands like `exists`, `set`, etc.?

Comment: @totsubo Yes, I do agree that the manual could be clearer. Maybe if I phrase it that way? "`dict remove` will remove keys returned by `dict keys` (topmost keys)" And yes, nested keys work with specific commands.

Comment: The difference between them is two-fold: `dict unset` works on dict-holding _variables_ and handles nested keys, and `dict remove` works on dict _values_ and handles removing multiple keys at once.